# How to connect to golang process with dlv?

Tags: go

I am trying to use the dlv tool for golang to setup a debugger on a remote go process. I have built the container with the command:

```
go build -mod vendor -o ./build/output/myapp -gcflags="all=-N -l" -ldflags"-X" ./cmd/myapp
```

The container is spun up with docker-compose and spins up correctly. I then try and use dlv once it is up and running by running the command.

```
sudo dlv --listen=:2345 --headless=true --api-version=2 attach 1568
```

However I get a terminal error which is

> could not attach to pid 1568: could not open debug info - debuggee
> must not be built with 'go run' or -ldflags='-s -w', which strip debug
> info

As you can see the container is not built with run nor the mentioned flags. Why do I get this error with dlv and how can I successfully setup the debugger on the go process with dlv?

Comment: You mentioned you're running the go code in a container. Are you running `dlv` inside or outside the container? If outside, are you using the correct (host) pid for the target process, rather than the in-container pid?

Comment: dlv is outside the container. I am using the PID for the process that is running inside the container. I am running docker top <container-name> to get the PID of that process and then plugging that into dlv

Comment: Did you consider to open a [GitHub](https://github.com/go-delve/delve) issue?

Comment: I always consider it when I have wierd issues. But wanted to do some more digging first.